# How to set the height for the < th > or < table > tag?

Tags: html, css, html-table, marquee

How to set the height for the < th > tag or the < table >. I found height=600px; as the property but its just going 600 pixels down from top of the screen but not setting the height of table as 600 px;

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <th style="width : 400px ;height:600px">
 <marquee direction=up behavior="scroll">
  hello
 </marque>
 </th>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

I'm just learning to grasp more grip on tables and marque tag. I need to scroll up some text say hello from bottom to top in the < th > tag but I'm unable to set the height. Its working good if I use `direction=left` or right because I have increased width but how do I set the height of the < th > or < table > . Well its increasing when I enter text but I want to do it explicitly

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome, the height of the `<th>` is 600px exactly. What browser are you using?

Comment: Uh oh. `<marquee>` and `<table>` based layout in the same question? Get your flame-proof spacesuits, everyone! :)

Comment: Im using the chrome is it working for you ? for me its the word hello going 2 rows up and ending but 600 px wont be just 2 rows height right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing it right as far as the table goes, for your `marquee` to expand vertically as far as its container just add `style="height: 100%;"` to it

Comment: +1 but what does height : 100 %  mean will it go from bottom to top of <th> tag size huh?

Comment: `% - Defines the height in percent of the containing block`, more info http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

Answer (score 1):

i think by adding style with height 100% will solve ur problem.

```
  <marquee direction=up behavior="scroll" style="height:100%">
  hello
 </marquee>
```

Comment: what do you mean by height : 100 %

Comment: height in % specifies the value in proportion (in this case in %tage to its containing block) rather than in absolute pixels.